# How to access custom properties from an Azure Alert sent to a Function App

Tags: azure

We are using an Action Group that sends the alert to a function app (powershell).
The alert rule has custom properties defined.

We can access the alert in the `$actionGroup.Body.Data`,using the azureMonitorCommonAlertSchema.

How do you access the customProperties from the alert rule? We can see in the JSON view of the alert rule, that the action group is configured with the `webhookProperties`. How do you get those in the powershell function app?

```
actions": {
            "actionGroups": [
                {
                    "actionGroupId": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourcegroups/yyy/providers/microsoft.insights/actiongroups/ag-func-01",
                    "webhookProperties": {
                        "foo": "bar",
                        "bar": "foo",
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

The only referal I could find in the Microsoft documentation is this one:
[Common alert schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-common-schema#sample-log-alert-when-the-monitoringservice--log-alerts-v2)

In the payload you will find the properties:

> {   "alertContext": {
> "properties": {
> "name1": "value1",
> "name2": "value2"
> },

To test the payload output the full body in the FunctionApp to the console. (Convert to json)